# Impediments to GC-MS characterization of petroleum products

Tags: analytical-chemistry, chromatography, mass-spectrometry

In an attempt to characterize, and sometimes to 'match' oil on feathers of birds, a laboratory utilize gas chromatographic - mass spectrometry. Persons likely to encounter oiled birds are advise to NOT wrap the bird in plastic, as this may affect results of the analysis, rather to use foil for containment, transport, and of course, to avoid cross-contamination with other hydrocarbons.

Exclusive of issue and presumed effects of cross-contamination by other hydrocarbons, how significant is short-term (< 48 hour) storage of oiled bird(s) on the assessment of contaminated plumage?

Thank you if you can provide an answer to this question.

Comment: What are "foil" and "plastic"?

Comment: @Karl Presumably aluminium foil and clingfilm. Clingfilm contains a load of plasticiser which easily contaminates anything it touches.

Comment: You'd need to know about the specific plastic composition (as matt_black points out, the identity and concentration of leachable plasticizers) and the rate at which these might be leached. Tough question but a literature search or a control experiment(s) will probably help.

Comment: @matt_black This stuff is usually graded food-safe, and does not contain plasticisers. It's usually PE + PiB, there is definitively no need to add expensive plasticisers which also make bad PR. PVC foils do contain plasticisers, but they're more for permanent use (windows, office supplies, ...)